# Problem with button ESC representation on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, button, representation

I'm using com.ibm.eNetworlk.ECL.ECLPS to get the buttons representations, I know some of them, but now I need to represent the button "ESC", but I couldn't find it out. Does some one can help me?

Comment: Show us code. How are you getting *any* other buttons?

Comment: I have a method that expect a String param, so I pass ECLPS.ENTER_STR when I want to pass a ENTER key.